# Querying whole database with filtering tables and columns and there joins etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, report

**Background**

My backend has a database in SQL server 2012 which has around 20 tables (maybe will increase in time) and each table will have approx 100 - 1000 rows initially might increase in future.

Now one of my colleague developed an web application which uses this database and let clients do CRUD and usual business logic.

**Problem**

My task is to create a reporting page for this web application, what I will be doing is to give client ability to export all of the data for all of there deep nested objects from SQL from all tables or only couple with all columns or only few... in excel, pdf and other formats in future. I might also need to query 3rd party in my business logic for gathering further information (out of context for now).

What can I do to achieve above ?

**What I know**

I can't think of any ***efficient and extendable*** solution, as it will involve 100s of columns and 20s of tables. All I can think of adding 100s of views for what I might require but it doesn't sound particle either.

Should I look into BI or SQL reporting or should this be done in code using ORM like EF ? or is there any open source code already out there for such ***Generic operations*** I am totally confused.

**Please note I am asking what to use not how to use. Hope I didn't offended anyone.**

Comment: You have't mentioned any budgetary constraints. If you want a proven efficient and extendable solution, buy one off the shelf.

Comment: For example there are a lot of cloud solutions that just point at a number of datasources and stick em together. IBM Watson. Tableau.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will be developing own user interface so third party apps are out of way, I just need to know "what approach to use" really to move forward

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't concerned with the client having access to all your database object names, you could write up something yourself without too much effort.  If you are creating a page you could query the system views to get a list of all table and column names to populate some sort of filtering (dropdowns, listbox, etc).

you can get a list of all the tables:

```
select object_id, name from sys.tables
```

you could get a list of all columns per table:

```
select object_id, name from sys.columns
```

object_id is the common key between the views.

Then you could write some dynamic SQL based on the export requirements if you plan to export through SQL.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am after, I know how to call tables and columns, please see edit in my question

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but you should be looking into BI like SSIS for processing the data or SSRS for a formatted report, if you want to go the Microsoft route.